# fos:user:promote Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When trying to promote user I have an error:

```
php bin/console fos:user:promote admin ROLE_ADMIN
```

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
>    Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

How can I debug it? Thanks,

Exception trace:

```
 () at \vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\User.php:122
 FOS\UserBundle\Model\User->addRole() at \vendor\friendsofsymfony\user-bundle\Model\User.php:416
```

Comment: You can call the comand with `-vvv` to get more informations.

Comment: Are you extending or otherwise doing something with `Model\User`? [Look at the source](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L122), it's expecting `$this->roles` to be an array, which is set in the constructor and otherwise in the class managed as an array. It's `protected`, though, so something may have access to modify it, or your console config isn't setup right and it's not getting initialized somehow.

Comment: [Here's the command itself](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Command/PromoteUserCommand.php), there really isn't much to it though. The question is why `$this->roles` isn't an array when you run the command.

Comment: I am also having the same problem this morning. Not sure what there is to go wrong. I have a __construct() and parent::__construct() in my User Entity.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now, also despite calling `parent::__construct()` and thus theoretically setting `$this->roles` array...